# How to trigger Asp:HiddenField OnValueChanged event using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have this `asp:hiddenField` control:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="AuxHiddenField" runat="server"/>
```

I would like to trigger its (server side) value changed event using Jquery:

```
Protected Sub AuxHiddenField_Changed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles AuxHiddenField.ValueChanged
    'some logic here      
End Sub
```

I tried:

```
$('#AuxHiddenField').val("Mohaha!!");
```

Jquery fails to find the element and nothing happens.
How do I solve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

ASP.net uses an algorithm to generate `ClientID`. By default it is based on the naming container's the control is contained in *successively*.

It's likely the ID in generated HTML is not `AuxHiddenField` but something like `ctl00_AuxHiddenField`.

Either set the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx):

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="AuxHiddenField" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

Or in jquery, using [attirute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/):

```
$('input[id$=AuxHiddenField]')  // id ends with AuxHiddenField
```

I personnaly don't like the `<%= Field.ClientID %>` way of doing this because if your javascript is in a separate file, it won't be processed by asp.net.

Further reading:

- [ClientID property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx)
- [All about ClientID mode in asp.net 4](http://beyondrelational.com/blogs/hima/archive/2010/07/16/all-about-client-id-mode-in-asp-net-4.aspx)

---

Changing programmatically a value with javascript does not fire the `change` event, you have to trigger it manually:

```
$('input[id$=AuxHiddenField]').val("any val").change(); // or .trigger('change');
```

In action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/d27Lj/).

---

**About the ValueChanged event**

Unfortunately, the HiddenField does not have the `AutoPostBack` property (makes sense afterall).
I think you will have to trigger a postback programmatically after changing the value.
If you are working ajax, use `__doPostBack()`, otherwise, submit your form `document.forms[0].submit()`.

Another solution would be to replace the HiddenField by an invisible TextBox:

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="mytextbox" Value="" Style="display:none;" AutoPostBack="true" OnTextChanged="mytextbox_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
```

Changing the value programmatically will raise the event server-side.
Please note that for hiding the textbox, you should not use `Visible="false` because then it is not rendered in final html, use the `Style="display:none;"` property (css).

Comment: Thanks Didier G. But the change event you are showing is the client side input change event. I need the server side HiddenField OnValueChanged event. How can I trigger the OnValueChanged event on server side?

Comment: Hm, don't recall this 'OnValueChanged' requirement. Anyway, HiddenField does not have `AutoPostBack` (makes sense). You probably would have to trigger the postback yourself with `__doPostBack()`. You could also change the HiddenField for a TextField with `display:none` for instance.

Comment: +1 for because if your javascript is in a separate file, it won't be processed by asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

To find a value:

```
$('#<%= AuxHiddenField.ClientID %>').val("Mohaha!!");
```

However, setting a value with JavaScript never fires a change event, and I don't think hiddens support it....